# GMAIL API Acces token duration

Tags: gmail, gmail-api, access-token, google-workspace, refresh-token

How can I extend the gmail api access token to 1 week?
I see that a service account is necessary?
To have a service account do I have to pay?
Since I tried to create one and it asks me to have google admin

The access token lasts only 1 hour and the refresh token too.

[image: Imagen]

If anyone has knowledge, can you help me before paying for something?

Answer (score 0):

Access tokens expire in on hour or 3600 seconds.

Refresh tokens are long lived and do not expire. They are used to request a new access token when it expires.

If your refresh tokens are expiring after a week it is because your app is still in testing.

Go to google cloud console on the oauth consent screen and put it in production.  No you do not need to verify your app at this time.  its two diffrent things.

[How to Fix Invalid Grant and Expiring Refresh Token Errors for Google OAuth](https://youtu.be/SYU-Zb4BJC4?si=i9637_AAMy3fKtL6)